# PHP isset server status

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP. A friend gave me the idea to do a mojang server status on our minecraft server page, so I started with this:
 **in my php code i have tried this:**

```
    <?
    $json = file_get_contents("http://status.mojang.com/check");
    if(!empty($json)) {
    $result = json_decode($json,true);
    }
?>
    minecraft.net


<? if (isset($result["minecraft.net"]) && isset($result["minecraft.net"]=="green")) {
       echo "OK"; 
    } 
?>
```

This is inside of my PHP file, but is only shows "minecraft.net". Why?

Regards,
Eric.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: If your condition fails, you have no information available. Add an `else` clause and do a `var_dump($result)`. What is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are producing a syntax error with this code:

`isset($var == "value")` results in a `unexpected T_IS_EQUAL` which might be surpressed be your server.

Also, as [Machavity stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803729/php-isset-server-status/20803840#20803904), you have a multidimensional array result.

So in the end, this is want you whant:

```
<?php
if (isset($result[0]["minecraft.net"]) && $result[0]["minecraft.net"]=="green") {
   echo "OK"; 
} 
?>
```

It is recommended to not use the `<?` shortag because it depends on server configuration. `<?php` will always work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're missing that there is a container array. `$result['minecraft.net']` should be `$result[0]['minecraft.net']`.

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents("http://status.mojang.com/check");
if(!empty($json)) {
  $result = json_decode($json,true);

  echo 'minecraft.net ';
  if ($result[0]['minecraft.net']== 'green')
    echo 'OK';
  else
    echo 'Off line';
} else
  echo 'mojang.com may be down';

?>
```

Comment: json_decode's second argument ensures that you get an array back. ;)

Comment: @MarkusKottländer I just saw that, I've fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your return object is giving you an array of arrays (truncated for brevity)

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["minecraft.net"]=>
    string(5) "green"
  }
}
```

So the proper output is

```
minecraft.net <? if (isset($result[0]["minecraft.net"]) && $result[0]["minecraft.net"]=="green") { echo "OK"; } ?>
```

When in doubt, `var_dump` your variables.

Comment: The second isset is still producing an `unexpected T_IS_EQUAL` error.

Comment: Good catch. I missed the second one being wrapped in `isset`